# Как отправить на сервер объект с фото

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios

Пользователь вводит некоторые данные и прикрепляет фото затем отправляет. Мне нужно на сервер отправить Например:

```
let data = {
    input1 = "Lorem",
    input2 = "Lorem2",
    file:"Тут будет файл"
}
```

Отправка происходит через axios vue

```
this.$axios.$post("server.ru",data);
```

Данные отправляется файлу php, можете написать код или просветите меня

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос используя FormData

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]